# How to send an array in dart post request

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to send messages to device groups with their `registration_ids`.

This my code:

```
List<String> tokens=["token1","token2"];
final  url='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
 http.post(url,headers:{
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Authorization":"key=mykey"
  ,"project_id":"proID"
},
body: 
  {
 "registration_ids" :tokens ,
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 }
}
```

When the app runs this error displays:

> Exception has occurred.
>   _CastError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved; I just encoded the body:

```
List<String> tokens=["token1","token2"];
final  url='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
 http.post(url,headers:{
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Authorization":"key=mykey"
  ,"project_id":"proID"
},
body:json.encode( 
  {
 "registration_ids" :tokens ,
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 }
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are having problems due to the registration is expecting a `JSON` string but you are passing list object to it. You can simply resolve that by casting your `List<String>` to `String`.

By casting the token list using `toString()` method you will get a String like this `"['token1','token2']"`

Here's the modified code:

```
List<String> tokens=["token1","token2"];
final  url='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
 http.post(url,headers:{
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Authorization":"key=mykey"
  ,"project_id":"proID"
},
body: 
  {
 "registration_ids" : tokens.toString() ,
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 }
}
```

Comment: not working, it is passing just as string not a list.